# Is there a geo hashing collection?

Tags: java, collections

I have a big array with a lot of geo location cords. When I want to get all of the point that is near to a given point with a given radius I go through all of the list and check it.

Is there a more efficent way to so this ? like geo indexing collection?
I know that mongodb does it for db , But I need somting like "GeoHash" if it exist.

Comment: Why not write your own? I haven't heard of other "geo-collections" outside the possibilities that mongo has. I guess actually using mongoDB would be overkill, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

(1) Use GeoHashing [see description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash), and convert each point into a hash, using a library like [geohash-java](https://github.com/kungfoo/geohash-java) .

(2) Use prefix string search to find out which points are closest to the target point.

However, do note that the comparison will be approximate (some points close together can have completely different geohashes).